# Find a simple formula for f(n)

Tags: combinatorics, permutation-cycles

Let $f_n$ be the number of ways to choose a permutation π of [n] and then a subset of the cycles of π. For instance, f(2) = 6 (check!). Find a simple formula for f(n)(not involving any sums!).

Would this be ${n \choose π} * {π \choose k}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a permutation with $k$ cycles, the number of subsets is $2^k$.

The number of ways to choose a permutation and then a subset of its cycles is thus:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n |s(n,k)|2^k=(n+1)!$$

Where $s(n,k)$ are [Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind): $|s(n,k)|$ is the number of permutations of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ with $k$ cycles.

---

The preceding formula is a special case of:

$$x(x+1)\cdots(x+n-1)=\sum_{k=0}^n |s(n,k)|x^k$$

It's often used as a definition of (unsigned) Stirling numbers of the first kind. It can then be used to prove the recurrence relation on Stirling numbers, which in turn, is used to prove the relation with permutation cycles. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind#Recurrence_relation) (I'll add a summary later to the answer).

Comment: Where does the π factor into this? In place of k, do i just put π? Also, since the questions asks for formula not involving sum, the answer will just be (n+1)!.

Comment: @hilh Yes, the answer is $(n+1)!$, the sum is just the way to find this formula. Note that the sum runs on the number of cycles, and $|s(n,k)|$ is the number of permutations of $\{1...n\}$ with $k$ cycles. There is no $\pi$ involved. Anyway, you can't have $\pi$ in the closed-form formula: it's not a known constant of the problem, it would be, at best, an arbitrary permutation (possibly a sum index, but here it's not how it's computed).

Comment: Could you explain how you get (n+1)! again?